# Node.js and https certificate error handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, error-handling

To make a long story short:

I'm building node app which making a request with **https** (the secure version of http). Whenever I miss-configure my request options, I'm having this error:

> Node.js Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames

Great... except of the fact that **the entire request code is wrapped with a valid `try..catch` block** (which works just fine.. checked that already). The code is basically something like this:

```
try
{
    https.request(options, (response) =>
    {
       // no way I making it so far this that error

    }).end();
}
catch(ex)
{
   // for some reason.. I'm not able to get here either
}
```

What I intend to do is to simply handle that error within my `try..catch` block

After reading some posts I've learned that this behavior is mainly because the `tls` module is automatically process the request and therefore making this error - this is a nice piece of information but it doesn't really help me to handle the exception.

Some other suggested to use this option:

```
rejectUnauthorized: false // BEWARE: security hazard!
```

But I rather not... so.. I guess my questions are:

1. Handling an error with a `try..catch` block should work here..right?
2. If not - is this behavior is by-design in node?
3. Can I wrap the code in any other way to handle this error?

Just to be clear - I'm not using any third-party lib (so there is no one to blame)

Any kind of help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `'error'` event handler on the request object returned by `https.request()` to handle that kind of error. For example:

```
var req = https.request(options, (response) => {
  // ...
});
req.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('request error', err);
});
req.end();
```

See [this section in the node.js documentation about errors](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/errors.html#errors_error_propagation_and_interception) for more information.

Comment: man.. I attached the `.on('error' handler` to the...response :( too late - going to sleep! thanks for the insight!